# Npm start is not working when trying to relaunch a react app

Tags: reactjs, npm, launch

I've already launched the project using npx create-react-app. The app opened up in my browser and everything was going great. My computer restarted overnight, and the browser tab hosting the app was closed. I'm trying to re launch the app using "npm start" in the terminal, but I am getting the following error:

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "start"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Did you mean one of these?
npm ERR!     npm star # Mark your favorite packages
npm ERR!     npm stars # View packages marked as favorites
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/guaclim/.npm/_logs/2023-01-31T15_34_16_068Z-debug-0.log
```

Npm start worked just fine when it came to launching the app the first time. I've tried updating and reinstalling npm. My json is also as it should be as far as I can tell :

```
 "name": "new-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I also attempted the following steps but it looks like there was an authorization issue:

npm install -g npm@latest -- to update npm because it is sometimes buggy.
rm -rf node_modules  -- to remove the existing modules.
npm install -- to re-install the project dependencies.

The errors i got:

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm',
npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.npm-i9nnxROI'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are in the correct directory?

Comment: can you try sudo

Comment: Good question, when i type "cd" into the terminal it does not appear that I am accessing the react app... Sorry in advance here this is my first time building with React. My file name is "new-app" but when i type that into the terminal, it says there is no such file or directory

Comment: @ShubhamKumar I'm sorry this is my first react app, not sure what you mean by try sudo

Comment: @Konrad you got it man, I had to play around with the terminal a bit and navigate to the correct file but it's launching now. Thank you!